# Equivalent of "almost everywhere" for "holds except on a set that is nowhere dense"

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory, cantor-set, almost-everywhere

When we say that a condition holds everywhere except on a set of measure zero, we can say that the condition holds *almost everywhere*.

I want to say that a condition holds everywhere except on a set that is nowhere dense (i.e. a set that does not contain an interval). What is the "almost everywhere" equivalent shorthand notation for saying this? "Approximately almost everywhere" is my own name for it, but I am wondering if a formal name exists.

Comment: Nowhere dense set (your definition) could be of measure 0 or measure 1 on the unit interval, i.e. the rationals (0) or the irrationals (1).

Comment: Is it *really* "everywhere except on a set that is nowhere dense" or is it "everywhere except on a countable union of nowhere dense sets"?  (The latter is "[meagre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set)" or "of first category".)

Comment: I didn't notice on first reading, but (as sort of pointed out by herb steinberg), your definition of nowhere dense is wrong. A set is nowhere dense if it's *closure* doesn't contain an interval. E.g. the rationals are dense (everywhere dense!) in the reals, but they do not contain an interval.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is common to say that a property holds "generically" if it holds except on a *meager* set. A meager set is a countable union of nowhere dense sets - because meager sets and sets of measure zero are both closed under countable unions, meager is a better analogue of measure zero than nowhere dense (for most purposes).

Answer (score 1):

No, *almost everywhere* is not everywhere except on a set that is nowhere dense. The reason is that nowhere dense sets could have positive Lebesgue measure, e.g. fat Cantor set. In general, there is no condition that holds everywhere except on a nowhere dense set because a nowhere dense set can have any positive measure.